# Why not create an instance of a UIView and straight away assign to a property instead of using implicit unwrapped optionals?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I am referring to the case below. The comments explain it well.

```
class HelloWorldViewController: UIViewController {
    
    var label: UILabel! //Why do this and then create an instance of UILabel and assign it to 'label'
    
    //When this can be done straight away?
    //var label = UILabel()
    
    override func loadView() {
        view = UIView()
        
        label = UILabel()
        label.text = "Hello World"
        view.addSubview(label)
    }
}
```

Comment: It's late, bu the only case I'm seeing is that you could `init` the  `HelloWorldViewController()`, but not load the view, and mimic the `@IBOutlet` behavior. So you'd avoid loading the extra `UILabel` in memory until it's really needed. But I'd say it's usually some "optimization" that we don't encounter often.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think the implicitly unwrapped optional is that popular, except when used in conjunction with Storyboards, where it would look like:

```
@IBOutlet var label: UILabel!
```

The option which I see more often, and personally like the best is this though:

```
lazy var label: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.text = "Hello World"
        // ...
        return label
    }()
```

No force unwrap, no optional, no fake initialization, initialized only if needed, and can access instance variables.

Comment: Why would you need lazy if there is no self required

Comment: @LeoDabus (cc: @SwiftEnthusiast): I'm sure, Leo, you know the answer: there's no _requirement_ to have it as lazy (and I never said it was), like I said it's _often_ is: often UI elements do use some instance members, and then `lazy` would be required. Also in many cases UI elements are not _always_ displayed, so there's no need to initialize them, unless they are actually needed. If neither is the key - yes, `lazy` can be omitted.

Answer (score 0):

As @klangfarb says in their answer, implicitly unwrapped optionals are usually used for outlets attached to Storyboards or nibfiles.

The idea is that if the Storyboard is set up and loads correctly, the outlets should not be nil. By making them implicitly unwrapped optionals, you cause an almost immediate crash, which shouldn't make it through even the most simplistic testing. Once you verify that your outlets aren't nil, not having to unwrap them every time you refer to them makes your code cleaner.

If you create your UI with code there's no good reason to use optionals of any kind.  Lazy vars, as klangfarb suggests, are an elegant way to create your UIKit components in code.

Comment: why would the variable marked as lazy though?

Comment: It doesn't have to be. By making it lazy it only gets created when you need it. That may or may not be useful. One handy thing about lazy vars is that they don't get invoked until after the object has finished its init, so self is available.

Comment: (It looks like Leo Dabus and klangfarb talked about this in some detail in the comments on klangfarb's answer.)